# send and receive string with bluetooth in 2 android devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

hi guys i am trying to send string from one phone to anther .

1) from one phone(client) i am clicking the paired listview to connect with the anther device(ConnectThread).

2) the second phone which is the server alerts that he has been connected with the device in step 1(AcceptThread).

3) after he get connected he start a new managerconnection thread and send along a string(in AcceptThread after connecting is sucessfull it starts a new managerConnection thread .

4) the other phone(after been connected to server it starts a new managerConnecting thread) should get the bytes from function read and put in the log how much bytes he read it seems its not getting any bytes at all can someone tell me what should i changed in my code?

```
package com.example.barhom.waves;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BlueToothServerActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "buckysmessage";
    private Button onBtn;
    private Button offBtn;
    private Button listBtn;
    private Button findBtn;
    private TextView text;
    private TextView serverStatus;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
    private AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread;
    private manageConnectedSocket manager ;
    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "waves";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_server);
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverStatus);

        // take an instance of BluetoothAdapter - Bluetooth radio
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            onBtn.setEnabled(false);
            offBtn.setEnabled(false);
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            findBtn.setEnabled(false);
            text.setText("Status: not supported");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            onBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOn);
            onBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    on(v);
                }
            });

            offBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOff);
            offBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    off(v);
                }
            });

            listBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.paired);
            listBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    list(v);
                }
            });

            findBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
            findBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    find(v);
                }
            });

            myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to the ListView
            BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                        long arg3)
                {
                    String value = (String)adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Listview clicked" ,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
                    // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        // setting the device to listen for connections(bluetooth)
        AcceptThread mSecureAcceptThread= new AcceptThread();
        mSecureAcceptThread.start();
    }

    public void on(View view){
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                text.setText("Status: Enabled");
            } else {
                text.setText("Status: Disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public void list(View view){
        // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // put it's one to the adapter
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Show Paired Devices",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public void find(View view) {
        if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
    }

    public void off(View view){
        myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        text.setText("Status: Disconnected");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
    }

    private class AcceptThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothServerSocket mmServerSocket;
        private boolean running = true;
        public AcceptThread() {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmServerSocket,
            // because mmServerSocket is final
            serverStatus.setText("Server Status: Listing for connection");
            Log.d(TAG, "SERVER IS LISING FOR CONNECTIONS");
            BluetoothServerSocket tmp = null;
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the client code
                tmp = myBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(NAME_SECURE, MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) {running = false; }
            mmServerSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            BluetoothSocket socket = null;

            // Keep listening until exception occurs or a socket is returned
            while (running) {
                try {
                    socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
                // If a connection was accepted
                if (socket != null) {
                    // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
                    manager=new  manageConnectedSocket(socket);
                    manager.start();

                    try {

                        mmServerSocket.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "SERVER IS CONNECTED");
                        String blahblah="asdasds";

                        manager.write(blahblah.getBytes());
                        break;

                    }catch (IOException e) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /** Will cancel the listening socket, and cause the thread to finish */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmServerSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    private class manageConnectedSocket extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream
            int bytes; // bytes returned from read()

            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);
                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
                Log.d(TAG,"WROTE A STRING TO ANTHER PHONE");
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
```

}

and the code for the client(the second phone):

```
package com.example.barhom.waves;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothServerSocket;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

public class BlueToothClientActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "buckysmessage";
    private Button onBtn;
    private Button offBtn;
    private Button listBtn;
    private Button findBtn;
    private TextView text;
    private TextView serverStatus;
    private ConnectThread mConnectThread;
    private BluetoothAdapter myBluetoothAdapter;
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices;
    private ListView myListView;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> BTArrayAdapter;
    private manageConnectedSocket manager ;

    // Unique UUID for this application
    private static final UUID MY_UUID =
            UUID.fromString("fa87c0d0-afac-11de-8a39-0800200c9a66");
    private static final String NAME_SECURE = "waves";
    private  BluetoothDevice device;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.bluetooth_client);
        serverStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.serverStatus);

        // take an instance of BluetoothAdapter - Bluetooth radio
        myBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if(myBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            onBtn.setEnabled(false);
            offBtn.setEnabled(false);
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            findBtn.setEnabled(false);
            text.setText("Status: not supported");

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your device does not support Bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

            onBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOn);
            onBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    on(v);
                }
            });

            offBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.turnOff);
            offBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    off(v);
                }
            });

            listBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.paired);
            listBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    list(v);
                }
            });

            findBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
            findBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    find(v);
                }
            });

            myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            // create the arrayAdapter that contains the BTDevices, and set it to the ListView
            BTArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
            myListView.setAdapter(BTArrayAdapter);
            myListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View v, int position,
                                        long arg3)
                {
                    String info = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
                    String address = info.substring(info.length() - 17);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"adress is"+address,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    device = myBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(address);
                   ConnectThread  mConnectThread=new ConnectThread(device );
                    mConnectThread.start();
                    // assuming string and if you want to get the value on click of list item
                    // do what you intend to do on click of listview row
                }
            });
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    public void on(View view){
        if (!myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent turnOnIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(turnOnIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth turned on" ,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bluetooth is already on",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT){
            if(myBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                text.setText("Status: Enabled");
            } else {
                text.setText("Status: Disabled");
            }
        }
    }

    public void list(View view){
        // get paired devices
        pairedDevices = myBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

        // put it's one to the adapter
        for(BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices)
            BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName()+ "\n" + device.getAddress());

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Show Paired Devices",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

    final BroadcastReceiver bReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // When discovery finds a device
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // add the name and the MAC address of the object to the arrayAdapter
                BTArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
                BTArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    };

    public void find(View view) {
        if (myBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            // the button is pressed when it discovers, so cancel the discovery
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        else {
            BTArrayAdapter.clear();
            myBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

            registerReceiver(bReceiver, new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND));
        }
    }

    public void off(View view){
        myBluetoothAdapter.disable();
        text.setText("Status: Disconnected");

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth turned off",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(bReceiver);
    }

    private class ConnectThread extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final BluetoothDevice mmDevice;

        public ConnectThread(BluetoothDevice device) {
            // Use a temporary object that is later assigned to mmSocket,
            // because mmSocket is final
            BluetoothSocket tmp = null;
            mmDevice = device;

            // Get a BluetoothSocket to connect with the given BluetoothDevice
            try {
                // MY_UUID is the app's UUID string, also used by the server code
                tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
            mmSocket = tmp;
        }

        public void run() {
            // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
            myBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

            try {
                // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
                // until it succeeds or throws an exception
                mmSocket.connect();
                manager=new  manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
                manager.start();
            } catch (IOException connectException) {
                // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
                try {
                    mmSocket.close();
                } catch (IOException closeException) { }
                return;
            }

            // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
          //  manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
        }

        /** Will cancel an in-progress connection, and close the socket */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
    private class manageConnectedSocket extends Thread {
        private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
        private final InputStream mmInStream;
        private final OutputStream mmOutStream;

        public manageConnectedSocket(BluetoothSocket socket) {
            mmSocket = socket;
            InputStream tmpIn = null;
            OutputStream tmpOut = null;

            // Get the input and output streams, using temp objects because
            // member streams are final
            try {
                tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
                tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
            } catch (IOException e) { }

            mmInStream = tmpIn;
            mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  // buffer store for the stream


            // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs
            while (true) {
                try {
                    int read = -1;
                    final byte[] bytes = new byte[2048];
                    for (; (read = mmInStream.read(bytes)) > -1;) {
                        final int count = read;
                        Log.d(TAG,"String size is"+count);
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device */
        public void write(byte[] bytes) {
            try {
                mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }

        /* Call this from the main activity to shutdown the connection */
        public void cancel() {
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }









}
```

any help will be great!
thanks.